# How to make it so the program doesn't print the default list opposed to the list I create

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this program to print out a custom dog profile in python, however it keeps printing out the default dog profile, please help

```
class dog:

    dogName = 'Mark'
    dogGender = 'boy'
    dogAge = 1
    dogDiseased = False
    DogProfile = [dogName, dogGender, dogAge, dogDiseased]

    @staticmethod
    def CreateDog(dogName, dogGender, dogAge, dogDiseased):
        DogProfile = [dogName, dogGender, dogAge, dogDiseased]

    def SeeDog(self):
        print(DogProfile)

John = dog

John.CreateDog('John', 'boy', 3, True)
John.SeeDog(John)
```